# How to set custom style to some columns in a nattable?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I need to set a custom style not for all, but some columns in a nattable. I can't set the configuration like this:

```
natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
```

because this sets the configuration to the whole table. I have to override the configuration only to specific columns. In my case the columns should have the horizontal align set like this:

```
setHAlign(HorizontalAlignmentEnum.RIGHT);
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NatTable styling docs](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling)

> To enable conditional styling, the custom style needs to be registered in the IConfigRegistry against the label defined before.

```
Style style = new Style();
// You can set other attributes here 
style.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, GUIHelper.COLOR_RED);

configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
    CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE,    // attribute to apply
    style,                  // value of the attribute
    DisplayMode.NORMAL,         // apply during normal rendering
    CELL_LABEL);    

        // apply for all cells with this label
```

To apply the CELL_LABEL label to your column follow the instructions from [NatTable configuration docs](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=configuration)

> Attaching a label to a cell
>
> Following the overall design convention, Layers can add labels to
>   cells. In order to attach a label to a cell(s) you need to implement
>   the IConfigLabelAccumulator interface. The
>   IConfigLabelAccumulator.accumulateConfigLabels() is called on each
>   layer. Every layer can add its labels to the LabelStack.
>
> The most common use cases are available out of the box, including but
>   not limited to:
>
> CellOverrideLabelAccumulator - applies labels to cell(s) containing a
>   specified data value ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator - applies labels
>   to all cells in a column You can make custom implementations for your
>   own rules