# How to config font color in nattable

Tags: nattable

I am trying to change font color within body cell of nattable.
But it is not working.
Could anyone present snippet code for this functionnality for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation to get started with NatTable basics.

Getting Started Tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html
Styling documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling

If these informations doesn't help, have a look at the NatTable examples application or search StackOverflow.

[How to set custom style to some columns in a nattable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799492/how-to-set-custom-style-to-some-columns-in-a-nattable)